# Pump spell sequence in MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I attack with my [Voltaic Brawler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVoltaic%20Brawler%5d) (3/2), then cast [Built to Smash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBuilt%20to%20Smash%5d) (+3/+3), [Uncaged Fury](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUncaged%20Fury%5d) (+1/+1 with double strike) and another [Built to Smash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBuilt%20to%20Smash%5d) (+3/+3) in that order, do I hit for 17 or 20?
Thanks in advance... basically a stack sequence question.

Comment: The order doesn't matter. You end up with a 10/9 with double strike no matter what order they resolve. It'll either do 10 dmg in the first combat dmg step, and possibly another 10 in the second combat dmg step.

Answer (score 4):

You will hit for 20. I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of double strike.

Double strike doesn't affect the actual power/toughness of the creature. It doesn't double the creature's power, it causes it to hit twice. You turn it into a 6/5 with the first Built to Smash, then a 7/6 with double strike with the Uncaged Fury, then a 10/9 with the second Built To Smash, then you pass priority and move to combat damage. It hits for 10, then you move to the second combat damage step because it has double strike, and it hits for 10 a second time.

It is possible to hit for 17, but you'd have to wait for the first combat damage step to occur before casting the second Built to Smash. In that case, it would only be a 7/6 the first time it hit, then you would make it into the 10/9 in time for second combat damage. Why would you do that? There's no obvious reason.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have pump spells and combat damage mixed up.  The sequence of combat is this:

1. Declare attackers
2. Both players get priority
3. Declare blockers
4. Both players get priority
5. Combat damage (if first strike/double strike is around)
6. Both players get priority (if ^)
7. Combat damage

Now, when you cast your spells, you're doing it while there is priority. If all your spells are cast at/before step 4, then your creature will have 10 power with double strike and deal damage during both combat damage steps.

Comment: Note that this does mean it's possible for a creature to have a different power on the first and second strike. If for some weird reason you really *wanted* to deal exactly 17 damage, or couldn't cast the last pump spell at first, or just made a mistake, you could wait to cast the second Built to Smash til after the first combat damage step, so it'd deal 7 damage, have its power increased to 10, then deal 10 damage.